# UITableViewCell transform is repeated inversed

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I am subclassing UITableViewCell with the purpose of putting a UISegmentedControl inside. Since the font of the UISegmentedControl is huge, I'd like to reduce it.
Here is what I am using for now:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:properFrame];
        self.segmentedControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.8f, .8f);
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.segmentedControl];
    }
    return self;
}
```

However, the segmentedControl shrinks once, then every time I scroll down the table and then up, the segmentedControl is enlarged  (!) by what appears to be about 1.2 factor, that is, the inverse of the transformation I requested.

iOS SDK used is 5.0, target platform - 4.0, Simulator version 5.0.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may not be what you want, but if you change the style of the `UISegmentedControl` to "Bar", it's a smaller, more condensed style. Might give you what you want without the need to figure out transformations.

Comment: Thanks, that was useful and very close to the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm not a 100% sure, but why don't you try to override the `-(void)layoutSubviews`
 method on your subclassed UITableViewCell and try to set the transformation of the segmented control from identity to 0.8f again...